# Why does SQL Server Return 0 for ceiling of positive values less than 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting some unexpected results from MS SQL Server and wondering if this is a bug or my misunderstanding of something?

When using `CEILING` I get the desired effect (rounding up to nearest integer) unless I use it against a value > 0 and < 1, in which case it returns 0...

Example:

```
SELECT CEILING(2/7)
```

is returning 0.

SQL Server 2017

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `SELECT 2/7;` is a positive value? (e.g. did you try it without introducing `CEILING()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does *integer* division.  So, `2/7` is `0`, not some fraction.

Compare:

```
select ceiling(2/7), ceiling(2.0/7)
```

Or:

```
select 2/7, 2.0/7
```

Comment: I think you should add: Commonly with `int` fields, you would do `ceiling(a * 1.0 / b)`